# New dictionary from comprehension with setten keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I've got two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'id': 1001, 'text': 'some text 1', 'key1': 11, 'key2': 12}
dict2 = {'id': 1002, 'text': 'some text 2', 'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}
```

And I want to get something like this, keep `'id'` from' `dict1` and subtract `'key1'` and `'key2'`:

```
dict3 = {'id': 1001, 'key1': 10, 'key2': 10 }
```

I've tried as following:

```
dict3 = {key: dict1[key] - dict2.get(key, 0) for key in ['key1', 'key2']}
```

but I don't know how to keep original `'id'`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine but I would use the `dict-comprehension` to **update** the dict and not **create** it. That way, I could apply it to a dict that is already **initialized** with the desired `'id'` value.

```
dict1 = {'id': 1001, 'text': 'some text 1', 'key1': 11, 'key2': 12}
dict2 = {'id': 1002, 'text': 'some text 2', 'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}

dict3 = {'id': dict1['id']}  # initialize it first
dict3.update({key: dict1[key] - dict2.get(key, 0) for key in ['key1', 'key2']})
print(dict3)  # {'id': 1001, 'key1': 10, 'key2': 10}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only two `dicts` with few element, its far more easier getting your required `dict` manually.

```
>>> d3 = { 'id':dict1['id'] , 'key1':dict1['key1']-dict2['key1'] ,
           'key2':dict1['key2']-dict2['key2'] }
>>> d3
=> {'id': 1001, 'key1': 10, 'key2': 10}
```